# Using prefersStatusBarHidden without loosing default statusbar visibility behavior (of hiding statusbar when on vertically compact environment)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have `prefersStatusBarHidden` dynamic return value, it does show/hide the statusbar, Except of one problem:

When `prefersStatusBarHidden` return value is `false`, the statusbar is shown no matter if we are on a vertically compact environment (which is not the default behaviour when not using `prefersStatusBarHidden`).

Is there any way to use `prefersStatusBarHidden` still be able to detect if we are on vertically compact environment and hide the statusbar.

My current code looks something like below:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var someStatusValue = false

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
        guard (someStatusValue) else { return true }

        // Here instead of returning `false`, if we are on VERTICALLY COMPACT ENVIRONMENT return `true` else `false`
        return false
    }

}
```

**Additional:** I am using UINavigationController based viewcontroller, and `View controller-based status bar appearance: YES` in info.plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just finally figured it out

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
    guard (someStatusValue) else { return true }

    if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.current.orientation)) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

I also have following line to register for orientation change in `viewWillAppear`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(orientationChanged(_:)), name: .UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
```

And the function which is responsible for recieving the notification and updating the statusbar:

```
func orientationChanged(_ note: Notification) {
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

Note: you must `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver` to unregister for orientation notifications in `viewWillDisappear`